# Samsung Photosphere orientations.txt data

Tags: photos, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Samsung (and perhaps other vendors) photosphere source files include the photographs and 2 text data files.

*sessions.meta* - contents are self explanatory, labelled metadata info about the sphere.

*orientations.txt* - unlabelled columns.

Below are sample contents of *orientations.txt*:

```
-0.28355762 0.95895493 7.3134253E-4 -0.19058217 -0.057101488 0.9800091 0.9398263 0.2777497 0.19895127 2.8249815
-0.18003005 0.96288395 0.20110609 -0.044745624 -0.21225126 0.97619015 0.9826429 0.16674495 0.081296444 2.9338377
-0.27238333 0.95405024 0.12488161 0.17231762 -0.07932246 0.98184246 0.946633 0.28895682 -0.14279357 2.9741824
-0.43306527 0.8942725 -0.112832405 0.09304 0.16886118 0.9812387 0.89654785 0.41444248 -0.15633103 2.746174
-0.44042435 0.87723744 -0.19099967 -0.14356112 0.14119293 0.97951764 0.8862373 0.45882356 0.06375239 2.631776
```

**My question is, does anyone know what these columns in orientations.txt represent?**

- 1 row per image
- 10 columns of floats
- no field names
- I assume it may have to do with roll, pitch and yaw, but I'm not certain.
- Perhaps accelerometry output?

Thank you very much in advance.

This is broadly related to these two other questions, but they don't really address my question.

[Get the original photos after using PhotoSphere?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61183/get-the-original-photos-after-using-photosphere)

[Is there any way to re-render a photosphere?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/is-there-any-way-to-re-render-a-photosphere/137551#137551)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that most elements are less than 1. Moreover the first 9 elements seem to be always less than 1. It looked like elements of a rotation matrix. So I grouped these elements into 3x3 matrix and it happened to be orthogonal, and it is in fact [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

```
-0.28355762  0.95895493  7.3134253E-4
-0.19058217 -0.057101488 0.9800091
 0.9398263   0.2777497   0.19895127
```

If the phone is in landscape orientation and points to the North than the matrix is identity matrix:

```
 0.9999746    0.0067272037 0.0023434649
-0.0067065083 0.9999394   -0.008729676
-0.0024020493 0.008713738  0.9999592
```

The last element in the row is the sum of all elements of the matrix. I don't know why it is added, because it doesn't seem to have any physical meaning, but I guess that it is some form of a checksum.